# Installing R in RHEL 7

Tags: linux, installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, r, rhel-6

I took the following steps to install R in RHEL 7:

```
yum install epel-release
yum update
yum install  R
```

But I got errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.3.1-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: gcc-c++
Error: Package: R-core-3.3.1-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(dvips)
Error: Package: R-core-devel-3.3.1-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: tex(latex)
```

I tried several suggestions posted on the Internet but nothing seems to work or solve my issue. Can somebody help me install R? It should be a simple three steps process but now it became a nightmare for me to complete it.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.1 (Maipo)

Comment: What "several suggestions" have you tried exactly?