# How to install R in CentOS 7 under Docker?

Tags: linux, installation, centos, docker, r

I downloaded CentOS from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/) but I am unable to install R with yum or rpm. Commands, such as `yum install R`, `yum install Rcore` and `rpm install R`, do not work.

```
sh-4.2# rpm --query centos-release
centos-release-7-3.1611.el7.centos.x86_64
```

**How can I install R in CentOS 7 under Docker?**

Answer (score 2):

By this [Red Hat](https://superuser.com/questions/1145180/installing-r-in-rhel-7) question, I found the command

```
yum install epel-release
```

or with extras

```
yum --enablerepo=extras install epel-release
```

after which, the `yum` was able to find `R` (600MB with dependencies).

```
yum install R
```